# foreach statement in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, textbox, foreach, listviewitem

```
private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.ResetText();

    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (lvi.Checked == true)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(lvi.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

I think what I am trying to do there is obvious, but the result is that the listboxitem that I just click is not displaying in the textBox. It's displayed after I check an other one (or uncheck the same one).
Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ItemChecked` event instead of the `ItemCheck` event (the latter is raised before the check state changes on the item, and this is why you only see its effect after checking another item).

Comment: Great :) ...also, you might want to accept the answer (by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it).